# Mysql/mariadb "Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist"

Tags: mysql, mariadb, archlinux

Starting mariadb in arch linux results in "Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist" on systemctl logs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When installing the package, there's a notice that I didnt read about "You need to initialize the MariaDB data directory prior to starting
the service. This can be done with mariadb-install-db command, e.g.:
mariadb-install-db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql"
Just do that and you'll get it.